# There is no extended operation handler registered with the Directory Server for handling extended operations with a request OID of 1.3.6.1.1.21.1'

Tags: transactions, ldap, rollback, unboundid-ldap-sdk, opends

I am using `OpenDS LDAP server` and `Unboundid-ldapsdk-2.3.8.jar`. When I am requesting for an extended operation like `StartTransactionExtendedRequest` or `StartTransactionExtendedResult` to get the `transactionID` then I got an error with a `ErrorCode = 53(Unwilling to perform )` and `messageID = 2`.

The complete ERROR msg given below:

> extendedResult =
>   (com.unboundid.ldap.sdk.extensions.StartTransactionExtendedResult)
>   StartTransactionExtendedResult(resultCode=53 (unwilling to perform),
>   messageID=2, diagnosticMessage='There is no extended operation handler
>   registered with the Directory Server for handling extended operations
>   with a request OID of 1.3.6.1.1.21.1')

My code snippet given below also:

```
    StartTransactionExtendedResult extendedResult;
    ASN1OctetString txnId = new ASN1OctetString();
    String ldapDnForUser = "ou=organization,dc=ecn_id,dc=org";
    try {
        StartTransactionExtendedRequest tReq = new StartTransactionExtendedRequest();
    extendedResult = (StartTransactionExtendedResult) this.ldapCon.getlConn().processExtendedOperation(tReq);

} catch (LDAPException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
    extendedResult = new StartTransactionExtendedResult(new ExtendedResult(ex));
}

txnId = extendedResult.getTransactionID();
LDAPTestUtils.assertResultCodeEquals(extendedResult, ResultCode.SUCCESS);
```

Please anyone help how to fix it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenDS does not support RFC5805 about LDAP transactions.

As a consequence you're trying to use a control that is not supported by OpenDS.

To see what are the controls OpenDS supports, follow that link :

https://java.net/projects/opends/pages/2_4_SearchingUsingControls

Comment: But i found the solution in there official website. so please tell me about that. @Mathieu M.

[the official website link] (https://docs.ldap.com/ldap-sdk/docs/javadoc/com/unboundid/ldap/sdk/extensions/StartTransactionExtendedRequest.html)

Comment: The Unboundid LDAP SDK supports RFC5805, but the OpenDS server that you said you're using does not support it.

Comment: But do you have any idea or a way to maintain transaction from client-end (i.e getting transaction id, and after transaction commit it)??